# 0_specialized _fatalerrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game, where I am getting this error:

> 0_specialized _fatalerrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never

here is the code where I believe the crash is at:

```
func goToCongratsScene() {

  if countTouches > 5  {  
    let gameScene:GameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)  
    let transition = SKTransition.reveal(with: SKTransitionDirection.down, duration: 0)  
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
  }
}
```

> The Game Scene

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(248), green: CGFloat(248), blue: CGFloat(248), alpha: CGFloat(255)) //SKColor

    var message = "Good Job! "
    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold")
    label.text = message
    label.fontSize = 22
    label.fontColor = SKColor.blue
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.black
    label.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(label)

    run(SKAction.sequence([

      SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0),
      SKAction.run(){

        var scene =  GameOver(size: self.size)
        let skView = self.view! as SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        skView.presentScene(scene)
     }
    ]))
  }
}
```

Comment: Add some breakpoints in your code to detect at which code block the app is crashing. For example is "didMove" called or does the crash happens before

Comment: when I add a breakpoint, and start playing the game it says that their is a breakpoint in that section

Comment: add breakpoints until you get to the line that crashes your app. then you clikc "go to next breakpoint" and when it crashes you know which line the problem is on.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a difficult time recreating your problem in the question, so I just rewrote it for you. Here is a simple game...  you tap six times on main screen to win... then it automatically makes you lose after 1.5seconds (your delay)

on the game over screen you tap to reset.

If on the main screen you drag instead of tap, you lose instantly.

I can happily explain anything if you need. Hope it helps:

```
import SpriteKit

// Give us some functions that we can use in all of our scenes (inheritance):
extension SKScene { 

 // We don't need to use `self` anywhere for now,
 // because `size` and `view` are are already members of `SKScene`.

  func goToGameOverScene() {
    let scene       = GameOver(size: size)
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

    view!.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    view!.presentScene(scene)
  }

  func goToCongratsScene() {
    let congratsScene = Congrats(size: size)
    let transition    = SKTransition.reveal(with: SKTransitionDirection.down,
                                            duration: 0)
    congratsScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    view!.presentScene(congratsScene, transition: transition)
  }

  func goToGameScene() {
    let gameScene       = GameScene(size: size)
    gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    view!.presentScene(gameScene)
  }

  func makeLabel(text: String) {
    let label       = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold")
    label.text      = text
    label.fontSize  = 22
    label.fontColor = SKColor.blue
    label.position  = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(label)
  }
}

class GameOver: SKScene {

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    makeLabel(text: "Game Over!! Muahahaha!")
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    goToGameScene()
  }
}

class Congrats: SKScene {

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    backgroundColor = SKColor(red:   CGFloat(248),
                              green: CGFloat(248),
                              blue:  CGFloat(248),
                              alpha: CGFloat(255))

    backgroundColor = SKColor.black  // Not sure which color you wanted :)

    makeLabel(text: "you won... or did you?")

    run(.sequence([
      .wait(forDuration: 1.5),
      .run() { self.goToGameOverScene() } // We have to use `self` here because in closure.
    ]))

  }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

  var countTouches = 0

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    makeLabel(text: "Tap six times to 'win'~!")
  }

  // Six taps to win!
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    countTouches += 1
    if countTouches > 5  { goToCongratsScene() }
  }

  // Game over if you move your finger!
  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    goToGameOverScene()
  }
}
```

I think your problem came from trying to swap scenes around inside of `didMoveToView` and closures... and using `self` can get confusing quickly like that.

Here, I just spaced everything out, gave it its own function, so you can follow where moves to where a bit easier I think.